# bus error 10 in C

Tags: c, macos

I am a new beginer in C, I am doing tasks from USACO, this is the "gift1" task. I would like to think solutions my self, so if you just tell me why I get this bus error 10 instead of gaving me the answer of this task, that will be grateful grateful.

I am using OS X System, and gcc(from Xcode) version is

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Here is my code(still not finished yet):

```
/*
LANG: C
TASK: gift1
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *input_file, *output_file;

int total_people, giving_to_counter, accepting, having[9];

char giver[9][13], receiver[9][13], person;

int people_scaner, people_judger;

int main () {
    input_file=fopen("gift1.in", "r");
    output_file=fopen("gift1.out", "w+");

    fscanf(input_file, "%d\n", &total_people);

    people_scaner = 0;

    while(people_scaner<total_people){
        fscanf(input_file, "%s", giver[people_scaner]);
        people_scaner ++;
    }

    fscanf(input_file, "%s", &person);
    printf("%s\n", &person);

    people_judger = 0;

    do{
        people_judger ++;
    } while (
        strcmp(&person, giver[people_judger]) !=0
        );

    fscanf(input_file, "%d%d", &having[people_judger], &giving_to_counter);
    printf("%d\n%s\n%d\n%d\n", people_judger, giver[people_judger], having[people_judger], giving_to_counter);


    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use tihs code to read the file like this:

```
5
dave
laura
owen
vick
arm
dave  //if this line is "laura, owen, vick or arm" the code works good, but if it is "dave" I will get bus error 10?
200 3
laura
owen
vick
owen
500 1
dave
arm
150 2
vick
owen
laura
0 2
arm
vick
vick
0 0
```

Comment: check for the success of `fopen()` first, then that of `fscanf()`.

Comment: with `char person`, using `fscanf(input_file, "%s", &person);` is wrong, same with `printf("%s\n", &person);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared

```
char person;
```

`&person` can hold only one character. It cannot hold a name. Hence, the following lines are wrong and cause undefined behavior.

```
fscanf(input_file, "%s", &person);
printf("%s\n", &person);
```

Comment: thanks for this, my code can read "dave" in correct way, but I still get a bus error 10 after I changed `char person[13];`and all`&person`into`person`